# How to rewrite url http to https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code in .htaccess but it is not working.and no error occurs

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{localhost}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please change your tag to `.htaccess`

Comment: @HddnTHA  Which Tag?

Comment: Your question has `php` tag but it doesnt contains anything about php.

Comment: @HddnTHA Do you know the answer of my question?

Comment: If i know i will write an answer to your question.

Comment: @HddnTHA you can up vote it then so that this question get noticed by others who know answer

Comment: No. Because this question already has an answer in this community. You can make a search.

Comment: @HddnTHA send me link of that answer then.

Comment: @HddnTHA i have used that code but that sinnept is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `%{localhost}` is the problem as there is no such variable called `%{localhost}`.

Try this rule in your root .htaccess OR Apache server config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:protossl} !=s [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To have your url rewritten automatically from http to https, simply do this and change domain.com to your domain TLD:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```